# View a MediaWiki as it was at a given date?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to make an entire MediaWiki appear as it stood at a given date, i.e. all pages automatically show the last revision before that date. Currently all I can do is scrolling through each page's revision history and selecting the right one manually, which is extremely inefficient.

Would be great if there was a way to do this live, if not I'm also open to making a dump of a wiki's state at a given date (afaik dumping software usually only grabs the current state).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's very hard to recreate the state of a wiki at a given point in time because the content of a page depends on other pages, and the page history will turn back the clock for the current page but not for any other pages.

So for example, if page A contains `foo {{:B}}` and page B contains `bar`, then the rendered content of A will be `foo bar`. Now if someone edits A to say `FOO {{:B}}` and B to say `BAR`, and you go back in time, MediaWiki will fetch the old state of A (`foo {{:B}}`), the current state of B (`BAR`), and render that as `foo BAR`, which is not a state that ever existed.

There are some attempts to show faithful representations of old versions. The [Memento](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Memento) extension tries to reconstruct the state of a page at a given time by messing with MediaWiki internals to load all templates, images etc. in their old state. It can be controlled by `Accept-Datetime` headers (various browser extensions can add that transparently to all requests).

For Wikipedia, you could also use the [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/) which stores HTML snapshots of the old revisions of pages.

Comment: Memento sounds great, but is there a way to make it (or something similar) work with a wiki that doesn't have it installed on the server?

Comment: No. I expanded the answer to explain better why this is hard. You need to change how MediaWiki parsed wikitext to get the (mostly) faithful representation of an old page; that's not something you can do without installing an extension.

Comment: Then how come going into a page's history and viewing an older version works? For my purposes the way that tends to look would be enough as a fallback when memento isn't available.